# detect is localhost AWS Serverless framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless-offline

i'm running my serverless with serverless offline library, i'm running using `sls offline` and i have several. how i detect is my lambda API triggered from localhost or server? thank you

i already try like process.env.IS_LOCAL, process.env.AWS_EXECUTION_ENV but returning undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to add something like `console.log(process.env)` in your lambda handler to learn what environment variables exist in both cases called either from localhost or server, then see what you would use to detect how lambda is triggered.

for example:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: {"env": process.env},
    };
    console.log(process.env)
    return response;
};
```

Would return:

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": {
    "env": {
      "AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_VERSION": "$LATEST",
      "AWS_SESSION_TOKEN": "TOKEN",
      "LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT": "/var/task",
      "LD_LIBRARY_PATH": "/var/lang/lib:/lib64:/usr/lib64:/var/runtime:/var/runtime/lib:/var/task:/var/task/lib:/opt/lib",
      "AWS_LAMBDA_LOG_GROUP_NAME": "/aws/lambda/credential-exfiltration",
      "AWS_LAMBDA_RUNTIME_API": "127.0.0.1:9001",
      "AWS_LAMBDA_LOG_STREAM_NAME": "2023/07/11/[$LATEST]c50b302786f4448ba80c142eea1c94fa",
      "AWS_EXECUTION_ENV": "AWS_Lambda_nodejs16.x",
      "AWS_XRAY_DAEMON_ADDRESS": "169.254.79.129:2000",
      "AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME": "credential-exfiltration",
      "PATH": "/var/lang/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/:/bin:/opt/bin",
      "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION": "us-east-1",
      "PWD": "/var/task",
      "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY": "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY",
      "LANG": "en_US.UTF-8",
      "LAMBDA_RUNTIME_DIR": "/var/runtime",
      "AWS_LAMBDA_INITIALIZATION_TYPE": "on-demand",
      "NODE_PATH": "/opt/nodejs/node16/node_modules:/opt/nodejs/node_modules:/var/runtime/node_modules:/var/runtime:/var/task",
      "AWS_REGION": "us-east-1",
      "TZ": ":UTC",
      "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID": "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID",
      "SHLVL": "0",
      "_AWS_XRAY_DAEMON_ADDRESS": "169.254.79.129",
      "_AWS_XRAY_DAEMON_PORT": "2000",
      "AWS_XRAY_CONTEXT_MISSING": "LOG_ERROR",
      "_HANDLER": "index.handler",
      "AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_MEMORY_SIZE": "128",
      "NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS": "/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt",
      "_X_AMZN_TRACE_ID": "Root=1-64ad16dd-11b6c8747177397c3f4f0f2e;Parent=49939b5605c39c50;Sampled=0;Lineage=920b0c92:0"
    }
  }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT` as in

```
const isAws = !!process.env.LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to determine whether the Lambda API is triggered on the localhost or server, you can use `serverless offline plugins` then you can simply use the IS_OFFLINE environment variable. If you invoke Lambda using `sls offline` process.env.IS_OFFLINE value will be `true`.
in package.json you can add this dependency :

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "serverless-offline": "^8.8.0"
  },
```

in serverless.yml you can add this line :

```
# Plugins
plugins:
  - serverless-offline
```

This is the related documentation that you can read
[link](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-offline#:%7E:text=via%20aws-sdk.-,The%20process.env.IS_OFFLINE,and%20throughout%20the%20plugin.,-Docker%20and%20Layers)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `serverless-offline` plugin, the best approach is to use `process.env.IS_OFFLINE` variable documented [here](https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline#the-processenvis_offline-variable).